# Sending multiple chunks of readableStream

Tags: javascript, next.js, react-hooks, next.js13, openai-api

I am building a chatbot that should be able to consume the  stream of responses from the replicate model
I am using useCompletion() hook as per the documentation here: https://sdk.vercel.ai/docs/api-reference/use-completion

The expectation is that every new line (\n) chunk in the AI responses is shown as a new message component.
It fails to run when the chatbot response contains at least 2 chunks.

I am unable to comprehend the exact reason for the error.

`Error [ERR_METHOD_NOT_IMPLEMENTED]: The _read() method is not implemented`

in /api/chat/route.ts

```
import { Replicate } from 'langchain/llms/replicate';
import { StreamingTextResponse, LangChainStream } from 'ai';
.................
export async function POST(
    request: Request,
    { params }: { params: { chatId: string } }
) {
    try {
        const { prompt } = await request.json();
        const model = new Replicate({
            model: 'meta/llama-2-7b-chat:ac944f2e49c55c7e965fc3d93ad9a7d9d947866d6793fb849dd6b4747d0c061c',
            input: {
                max_length: 2048,
                max_new_tokens: 2048,
                temperature: 0.1,
                system_prompt:
                  
                    '. You are currently in a conversation with your fan' +
                    companion.instructions +
                    '. Below are relevant details about ' +
                    companion.name +
                    "'s past and the conversation you are in. " +
                    relevantHistory +
                    '\n'
            },
            apiKey: process.env.REPLICATE_API_TOKEN,
            callbackManager: CallbackManager.fromHandlers(handlers)
        });

        // Turn verbose on for debugging
        model.verbose = true;

        const resp = String(
            await model.call(`${recentChatHistory}`).catch(console.error)
        );
        const cleaned = resp.replaceAll(',', '');
        const chunks = cleaned.replaceAll('\n\n', '\n');
        const responses = chunks.split('\n');

        await memoryManager.writeToHistory('' + chunks.trim(), companionKey);
        var Readable = require('stream').Readable;
        var s = new Readable();

        for (const chunk of responses) {
            const response = chunk.trim();
            if (response !== undefined && response.length > 1) {
                await prismadb.companion.update({
                    where: {
                        id: params.chatId
                    },
                    data: {
                        messages: {
                            create: {
                                content: response,
                                role: 'system',
                                userId: user.id
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
                s.push(chunk);
            }
        }
        s.push(null);
        return new StreamingTextResponse(s);
    } catch (error) {
        return new NextResponse('Internal Error', { status: 500 });
    }
```

client.tsx

```
'use client';
import { Companion, Message } from '@prisma/client';
import { FormEvent, useState } from 'react';
import { useCompletion } from 'ai/react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';

import { ChatForm } from '@/components/chat-form';
import { ChatHeader } from '@/components/chat-header';
import { ChatMessageProps } from '@/components/chat-message';
import { ChatMessages } from '@/components/chat-messages';




interface ChatClientProps {
    companion: Companion & {
        messages: Message[];
        _count: {
            messages: number;
        };
    };
}

export const ChatClient = ({ companion }: ChatClientProps) => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const [messages, setMessages] = useState<ChatMessageProps[]>(
        companion.messages
    );

    const { input, isLoading, handleInputChange, handleSubmit, setInput } =
        useCompletion({
            api: `/api/chat/${companion.id}`,
            onFinish(prompt, completion) {
                const systemMessage: ChatMessageProps = {
                    role: 'system',
                    content: completion
                };

                setMessages((current) => [...current, systemMessage]);
                setInput('');

                router.refresh();
            }
        });

    const onSubmit = (e: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        const userMessage: ChatMessageProps = {
            role: 'user',
            content: input
        };
        setMessages((current) => [...current, userMessage]);

        handleSubmit(e);
    };

    return (
        <div className="flex flex-col h-full p-4 space-y-2 max-h-screen ">
            <ChatHeader companion={companion} />
        
            <div className="flex-grow overflow-y-scroll">
                <ChatMessages
                    companion={companion}
                    isLoading={isLoading}
                    messages={messages}
                />
            </div>
             <ChatForm
                isLoading={isLoading}
                input={input}
                handleInputChange={handleInputChange}
                onSubmit={onSubmit}
            />
        </div>
    );
};
```

[image: Ezpected Outcome]

Comment: Image shows the expected output